# Creating ISO with dd on macOS: Operation not supported

Tags: iso-image, dd, macos-mojave

`sudo dd if=/path/to/img.iso of=/dev/rdisk2`
returns
`dd: /dev/rdisk2: Operation not supported`

The disk was formatted ExFAT on macOS.

```
#: TYPE         NAME      IDENTIFIER
0: GUID_part              disk2
1: EFI          EFI       disk2s1
2: Micr B Data  Untitled  disk2s2
```

I ejected the drive with `diskutil eject disk2` before using `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

that can't possibly create an iso.. 'if' means from, and 'of' means to.  If you want to create an ISO  then you need the 'of' to refer to the path of the ISO

and if you had messed up and made 'of' refer to a hard drive unintentionally, then you could lose the contents of the hard disk so be careful with the dd command! triple check your 'if' and 'of', and make sure you know which is which and that they are the right way around, paying particular attention to the 'of'!